# To know the number of objects being serialized at that time. DRF

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a serializer which will serialize an object. Is there a way to know if it's serializing one object or multiple objects at that time?

I have a serializer and I have a custom method field in that. I need to call one API if it's a single objects it is serializing or if it's serializing multiple objects, I need to call a different API.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your serializer, you can override the `__new__` and `__init__` magic methods like below:

```
class MySerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
        def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            kwargs.update({"has_many": kwargs.get("many", False)})
        
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
           has_many = self.context["has_many"]
```

So, while you are serializing your data, you can anytime check if the serializer has been instantiated with the `many=True/False` and, based on that, do what needs to be done.

Comment: Thanks. I will try and let you know if it didn't work.

Comment: `__new__` method did not work. I added super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs) to `__new__`.
Without many=True it gave /env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 56, in retrieve
    return Response(serializer.data)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data' this error. And with many=True it gave
/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 588, in __init__
    assert self.child is not None, '`child` is a required argument.'
AssertionError: `child` is a required argument this error

Answer (score 0):

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       request = kwargs['context']['request']
       has_many = True if not request.parser_context["kwargs"].get('pk', None) else False
```

This is the workaround I have created. But not perfect. But does the job. If someone has a better answer which is working. Please share here.